# VBA Excel 2010 CreateObject ExtendedProperty get image width attribute

Tags: vba, excel, createobject

I'm using similar kind of functions to get some property attributes like `Filename`, `bit depth`, `dimensions`, `size` etc by using some vba code. The last line of that function would be something like the following:

```
PicSize = CreateObject("Shell.Application").Namespace(vPth2).Parsename(sPic2).ExtendedProperty("size")
```

Now, I want to get the height and width of that image file. I've put `height` and `width` in the `ExtendedProperty` attribute value but it's not giving me the height and width of that file.

Note that, in the property dialog box of that image file, in the summary tab, it is showing `Bit depth` but putting this did not work. Then I put `bitdepth` and it worked successfully. The names are not case sensitive.

Okay! Now all I want to get the height and width of that selected image file. How can I do that? I mean what to put inside `ExtendedProperty()` to get height and width.

An early reply with solution would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Can't help with why `Height` and `Width` don't work, but `Dimensions` seems to work, returns a string like `?493 x 376?`

Answer (score 0):

I suggest the work around method

replace `size` in your code

```
PicSize=CreateObject("Shell.Application").Namespace(vPth2).Parsename(sPic2).ExtendedProperty("size")
```

to `Dimensions`
you will get something like `?493 x 376?`

now declare

a string `t = "?493 x 376?"`

'search the index of "x"

```
search_x = InStr(t, "x")
```

'we would got width and height by

```
width = Mid(t, 2, search_x - 2)

height = Mid(t, search_x + 2, Len(t) - 8)
```

It is unknow why but I found that start at "2" in width and "-8" in height like that would give a number

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve the width and height of an image individually by modifying your code as follows:

```
Width = CreateObject("Shell.Application").Namespace(vPth2).Parsename(sPic2).ExtendedProperty("{6444048F-4C8B-11D1-8B70-080036B11A03} 3")

Height = CreateObject("Shell.Application").Namespace(vPth2).Parsename(sPic2).ExtendedProperty("{6444048F-4C8B-11D1-8B70-080036B11A03} 4")
```

For additional extended properties, see [Common Open Properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-wsp/2dbe759c-c955-4770-a545-e46d7f6332ed)